# Reactjs undefined context in function called by child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm quite new to ReactJS and Material UI. I'm trying to use context of my LeftList ES6 class inside a method that is called by child's onItemTap event.

```
class LeftList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    console.log('constructor:');
    console.log(context);
    this.state = { menuItems: [] };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu
            ref="menuItems"
            zDepth={0}
            menuItems={this.state.menuItems}
            onItemTap={this.onMenuItemClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  onMenuItemClick(e, index, item) {
    console.log('onMenuItemClick:');
    console.log(this.context);
  }
}

LeftList.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.func
};
```

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgC13.png) (I'm sorry I cannot paste images directly to a post)

As you can see, in the constructor context is defined, but inside the method called by onItemTap is undefined.

Do you know what is the problem?

As far as I know, the Material UI docs application uses almost the same solution (in [PageWithNav](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/app/components/pages/page-with-nav.jsx) class), however they're not using ES6 classes.

Comment: might it be related to this: https://github.com/goatslacker/alt/issues/283 ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. `this` keyword inside the `onMenuItemClick` method refers to `Menu`, that is called from, not to `LeftList` class. So I passed the context to `Menu` as a parameter:

```
<Menu
    ref="menuItems"
    zDepth={0}
    menuItems={this.state.menuItems}
    onItemTap={this.onMenuItemClick}
    context={this.context} />
```

Thank you very much for your help.